# Panel Alignment property update not working at runtime

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm new to Delphi and I'm trying to change a panel position dynamically at runtime. By default, my panel in this form has the Alignment property set to 'taLeftJustify'. At runtime, by pressing a button I create this new form and pass the kind of alignment that the user selected for the panel (left, right or center). According to this information, I change the form accordingly like so:

In my main form:

```
MyForm := TCustomForm.Create(Self);
MyForm.PassAlignment(ComboBoxInfo);
```

On my new form:

```
procedure TCustomForm.PassAlignment(const alig: string);
begin
  if alig = 'LEFT' then
  begin
   Panel4.Alignment := taLeftJustify;
  end;
    ...
end;
```

Whenever this code runs, nothing happens, no matter the position the user sets it to. My form stays at the default position it originally was set before the object creation.

Comment: Do you mean `Panel4.Align := alLeft` (aligns the panel) instead of `Panel4.Alignment := taLeftJustify` (aligns the caption of the panel)?

Comment: Errm, you are setting the alignment of text shown on the panel, i.e. its TAlignment.  That's **not** the same as the alignment position of the form.

Comment: As I said, I'm new to Delphi. Thanks for the information.

Comment: If in doubt, press F1 on the code (in this case "alignment" and see what the help files say.